# Normal subgroup to a subgroup is normal to the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that $N \trianglelefteq H$ and $N\neq H$, where $H\leqslant G$ and $H\neq G$. Does it necessarily hold that $N \trianglelefteq G$?

I know that the opposite is true, i.e. if $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $N\leqslant H$ then $N \trianglelefteq H$. To me, it does not seem like the converse should hold true, since $ghN(gh)^{-1}$ is not necessarily contained in $N$ but I haven't managed to find any counter examples. How can I proceed in proving that it does not necessarily hold?

Notational remarks:

$A\trianglelefteq B$ : $A$ is a normal subgroup of $B$

$A \leqslant B$ : $A$ is a subgroup of $B$

Comment: Note that what you are calling "the opposite" does not need $N\neq H.$ Having to add $N\neq H$ might show you why this is false.

Comment: Even a normal subgroup of a normal subgroup need not be normal.  $D_8$, the dihedral group of order $8$, is the smallest group exhibiting this phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "prove it" you only need to find a specific instance of a group where the property you are asking about doesn't hold. An example is $D_8$, the dihedral group of order $8$. Take as $N$ any group of order $2$ other than the centre and as $H$ any subgroup of order $4$ which contains $N$. Then $N$ is normal in $H$ but not in $G$.